# How do I position an element horizontally relative to one parent, and vertically relative to another?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm working on a web page which has elements with basically the following structure. There is a parent container, and it along with its subcontainers may each contain "lines" (represented in red in the example images) or further nested subcontainers (represented by yellow boxes with black borders). Each subcontainer may itself contain lines or further subcontainers, nested to an arbitrary depth. Obviously, lines inside subcontainers are narrower than lines in their parents.

Associated with each line, there are two additional bits of information, which should be displayed to the left and the right, respectively, on the lines, but outside of the entire container apparatus. These are represented by the purple and blue boxes in the pictures. The problem is positioning these. They should be vertically lined with the lines they are associated with, but horizontally aligned with each other, a constant distance from the sides of the outermost container, regardless of how far nested in subcontainers the associated line is.

Here is how things *should* look:

[image: good display]

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution if at all possible. However, the problem is that using absolute positioning, I can either use the outermost parent as what the absolute positions are relative to, and get the horizontal position right, or the lines as what the absolute positions are relative to, and get the vertical position right, but *not both*.

For example, with the following:

```css
#parent {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.subcontainer, .container {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.box {
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.righty {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 30px;
    right: -64px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.lefty {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 30px;
    left: -94px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="lefty"></div>
        <div class="righty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="lefty"></div>
        <div class="righty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="lefty"></div>
            <div class="righty"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontainer">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="lefty"></div>
                <div class="righty"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="lefty"></div>
                <div class="righty"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="lefty"></div>
            <div class="righty"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is this:

[image: bad image]

But then the blue and purple boxes are not horizontally aligned as they should be.

I can fix thing with JavaScript (here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jk4rm4f/)), but as the inner containers will be resizing, etc., regularly, it is annoying to have to constantly call these (and they tend to get distorted with zoom). If there were a pure CSS way to do this, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so what I basically did here is, I removed `position: relative` from `.box` and added it to `#parent` so now `.righty` and `.lefty` are *absolute* positioned *relative* to **`#parent`** and not **`.box`**, **`.container`** or **`.subcontainer`**

```css
#parent {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.subcontainer, .container {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.box {
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    _position: relative;
}
.righty {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 30px;
    left: 101%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.lefty {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 30px;
    right: 101%;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="lefty"></div>
        <div class="righty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="lefty"></div>
        <div class="righty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="lefty"></div>
            <div class="righty"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontainer">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="lefty"></div>
                <div class="righty"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="lefty"></div>
                <div class="righty"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="lefty"></div>
            <div class="righty"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be much more useful with some explanation.

Comment: Neat. This is close to what I need. Unfortunately, in my actual usage scenario, the red boxes and the blue/purple ones are not always the same height. I am also using `top: 0` on the .lefty and `bottom: 0` with .righty to align them respectively with the top and bottom of the red boxes. This doesn't work with your code. Though I may be able to tweak.